# Simplify nested loop over map

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm sure I don't need the nested inner loop, but how can this be achieved with one loop, any loop will do, just wanna get rid of the nested loop.

```
for (List<GoogleUsageMapping> recordsMap : recordsGroupByMetadataId.values()) {
    for (GoogleUsageMapping record : recordsMap) {
        System.out.println(record.getUsage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to get rid of it.

But you can of course *hide* it. It is still a nested loop in disguise though. Example:

```
recordsGroupByMetadataId.values()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .map(GoogleUsageMapping::getUsage)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

`Stream::flatMap` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function))) puts multiple streams together into one big stream, that is what flattens the nested loops into one big loop.

Comment: thanks for response, then it was just a wishful thinking on my part :)